# About A- star Algorithm

Tags: language-agnostic, a-star

In A-Star algorithm did we replace the node in frontier if a better path is found to a node currently on the frontier (open list)?

For Example: frontier has node B having evaluation function value f(x)= 25 and while exploring the children of node C we have a path from C to B having f(x)= 15 do we replace this value in frontier?

Comment: Does A* really qualify as artificial-intelligence?

Answer (score 0):

A-Star data structures:

**Open list:** Contains nodes that have not been expanded. Sorted by evaluation function **f(n) = g(n) + h(n)**. Initially contains the root. To expand a node you get the first one from the list. Besides you add the successors to the list.

**Closed list:** Contains nodes that have been expanded. When you are going to expand a node you check that it is not in the closed list. If it is you discard it.

Note that open list is **sorted by evaluation function** so that the node with the best evaluation function is placed in the front of the list.

Hope this helps.